# how to use python ML in android studio

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

to make it usable in android studio , i am converting the code to tensorflow lite

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(tflite_model)
```

BUT GETTING ERROR-
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str, debug_info_str, enable_mlir_converter)

i have also tried this one -but same error
[COLAB LINK](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Qz0L0vCMsy8gAyNTDRWxApTH9C6QcjKf?usp=sharing)

```
keras_file="linear.h5"
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, keras_file)
converter=lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tfmodel=converter.convert()
open( "Linear.tflite", "b").write(tfnodel)
```

Comment: add the full traceback and we can figure this out

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Qz0L0vCMsy8gAyNTDRWxApTH9C6QcjKf?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem might be versions. Check and make sure you are using the correct tensorflow version that will successfully convert python3.6 codes